# Using Special Character (-) in .htaccess file with PHP

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a rewrite rule in .htaccess. It has been working fine till now. But today, I tried to write a  rule and I have special character (-) in the variable. Something like this

```
http://127.0.0.1/website/client/ticket/update/KU0-QMV-882Q/
```

**KU0-QMV-882Q** is the Variable.

My rewrite rule is as follows

```
# This Directive will make Apache look first  

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^orders/pending$ orders.php?type=pending

RewriteRule ^orders/completed$ orders.php?type=completed

RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php

RewriteRule ^login$ login.php

RewriteRule ^ticket/open$ open-ticket.php


RewriteRule ^order/view/(\w+)$ show-order-details.php?id=$1 

RewriteRule ^ticket/update/(\w+)$   update-ticket.php?ticket_no=$1
```

Now when I try to access the URL it gives a 404 NOt Found Error.

So what do I need to write in the .htaccess file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Pratik G

Comment: ALWAYS the first thing to do when debugging rewriting rules is to ENABLE THE REWRITE LOG! It tells you in detail what is going on when a request is processed.

Answer (score 3):

In your rule `\w+` means every letters, digits and underscore but not hyphen. You should use `[\w-]+` instead.

Comment: Note that the URL in the example will still not work because of the trailing slash. Adding the /? before $ will make sure that URL is matched with or without trailing slash. `RewriteRule ^order/view/([\w-]+)/?$ show-order-details.php?id=$1`